# Finding Descendants and Ancestors of Adjacency List in SQL Alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, adjacency-list, adjacency-list-model

If I have an [adjacency list relationship as described by the `Node` class here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships), how would I get all of the [`descendants`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29#Terminologies_used_in_Trees) of that node? 
All of the `ancestors` of that `Node`?